# Spring custom filter execute only 1 time on specified url

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security, servlet-filters

I'm extending a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter overriding the configure method.
My goal is to place a filter on a specific URL that bypass the login page and make a manual authentication. To do that i need the filter to be executed only the first time the user try to reach the SECTION_WITH_FILTER url.
That's my code:

```
@Autowired
MyFilter myFilter;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    logger.debug("<CONFIGURE HTTPSECURITY/>");

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login*.*", "/error.*", "/resources/**", "/javax**/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/SECTION_WITH_FILTER/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/", "/*.jsf", "/**/*.jsf", "/*.faces", "/**/*.faces").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.jsf")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(false)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll()
            .and().csrf().disable();
    http
            .addFilterBefore(myFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

My problem is that the filter starts after every submit in any form of the website.

I already tried with a FilterRegistrationBean used also for setting the filter only when the user goes to a specific URL:

```
 @Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration() {

    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(myFilter);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/SECTION_WITH_FILTER/**");
    registration.setName("myFilter");
    registration.setEnabled(true);
    return registration;
}
```

But using this method a StackOverflowError exception is thrown.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with    path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:589)
...
```

How can i change my code to make a filter specified for a single url that starts only the first time the user try to reach it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the `OncePerRequestFilter`, override the `doFilterInternal` method to do your own business, and if some urls should not filter, you can override the `shouldNotFilter` method.

this filter is used to identify that a request is already filtered. The default implementation is based on the configured name of the concrete filter instance.